# Bing/msn bots is heavily requesting random of my website

Tags: plugins, security, robots.txt, shared-hosting, virus

I am facing a big problem with my server. I have a website that keeps getting massive page requests coming from "Bing/Msn" bot every second or two and the ip changes now and then. Which is putting a heavy load on my server.

My CPU is constantly over 90%

I tried to block the bot from htaccess and robots.txt but they don't seem to have any effect.

If anyone has an idea how to defeat this it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

[image: Wordfence live traffic]

Comment: Did you try the page in the user agent, https://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm ? There's useful information there: you may be able to sign up for the Bing Webmaster console and control it from there, or there's a 'how do I report an issue' link too.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a WordPress issue really though

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's good to know, i'm sure it might come up handy someday !

For now what i did is i reduced the crawl rate of Bing and Google to the absolute minimum from "Search console" and i added the crawl rate also in the robots.txt file, plus i added wordfence to block any malicious bots that pass on as google and to block it if it exceeds a certain amount of requests within 1 minute.

That gave me a great result and relieved the extra pressure from the server.

Thank you !